# Hibernate search: org.hibernate.search.util.common.SearchException HSEARCH000610?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I´m using hibernate search to create a metasearch engine, when I compile the project it does not give me any error but when I execute the request it gives me the following error:

```
org.hibernate.search.util.common.SearchException: HSEARCH000610: Unknown field 'CODIGO'.
Context: indexes [Vehiculo]
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.backend.scope.spi.AbstractSearchIndexScope.fieldInternal(AbstractSearchIndexScope.java:150)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.backend.scope.spi.AbstractSearchIndexScope.field(AbstractSearchIndexScope.java:138)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.backend.scope.spi.AbstractSearchIndexScope.fieldQueryElement(AbstractSearchIndexScope.java:205)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.search.predicate.dsl.impl.MatchPredicateFieldMoreStepImpl.<init>(MatchPredicateFieldMoreStepImpl.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.search.predicate.dsl.impl.MatchPredicateFieldStepImpl.fields(MatchPredicateFieldStepImpl.java:26)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're tring to search on the index field `CODIGO` and Hibernate Search is telling it doesn't know about that field.

Your schema needs to be declared, and that happens through [annotations on entity properties](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started-mapping) or an equivalent [programmatic mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#hsearch-mapping-programmaticapi).

There is [some support for dynamic fields](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-index-field-dsl-dynamic), but that involves the more complex [bridge APIs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_classbridge), and if you want *everything* to be dynamic ("schemaless"), Hibernate Search will probably fall short.